# Методы шаблонного класса и enable_if

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Возникла необходимость использовать конструкцию, позволяющую отсеять ненужные типы при определения метода шаблонного класса.

Порыскал и наткнулся на enable_if, однако если для определения целых классов и отдельных функций проблем не возникает, то для определения конкретных экземпляров методов с enable_if я никак не могу разобраться.

Хотелось бы получить что-то на подобии этого:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class C {
    public:
        template <typename Enable = void> void foo();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral_v<T>>::type>
void C<T>::foo() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    C<float> A;
    C<int> B;
    
    A.foo(); // Ошибка компиляции
    B.foo(); // Вывод: test

    return 0;
}
```

Конкретно у этого кода выходит ошибка, компилятор ругается на то, что не может сопоставить `C<T>::foo()` существующему объявлению

Answer (score 1):

1. использование `std::enable_if` `std::is_integral_v` требует включения заголовочного файла `type_traits`
2. `std::enable_if` может понадобиться при использовании SFINAE, а чтобы просто запретить использование метода при определенных условиях, достаточно использовать `static_assert`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class C
{
    public: void foo()
    {
        static_assert(::std::is_integral_v<T>);
        ::std::cout << "test" << ::std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C<float> A{};
    C<int> B{};
    
    A.foo(); // Ошибка компиляции
    B.foo(); // Вывод: test

    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:24,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:24,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aclass+C%0A%7B%0A++++public:+void+foo()%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++static_assert(::std::is_integral_v%3CT%3E)%3B%0A++++++++::std::cout+%3C%3C+%22test%22+%3C%3C+::std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++C%3Cfloat%3E+A%7B%7D%3B%0A++++C%3Cint%3E+B%7B%7D%3B%0A++++%0A++++A.foo()%3B+//+%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%0A++++B.foo()%3B+//+%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4:+test%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Как я понимаю, при таком исполнении метод просто не будет доступен для нецелочисленных типов, однако хотелось бы оставить возможность доопределять его для других типов.

Comment: @brattok Для поддержки других типов просто добавляйте соотв. проверки внутрь `static_assert`.